# How to set up PostgreSQL database with associations between tables (foreign keys) with Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, associations, sequelize.js

I'm using PostgreSQL, Sequelize, and Sequelize-cli.

Using sequelize-cli and some manipulation in an IDE I set up the following model and migration file (simplified for the example, I didn't include the "Users" migration file):

**Model File**

```
// models/annotation.js
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Annotation = sequelize.define('Annotation', {
      userId: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {model: "User", key: 'id'},
      },
      url: DataTypes.STRING,
      source: DataTypes.STRING,
      body: DataTypes.TEXT,
      exact: DataTypes.TEXT,
  }, {
      classMethods: {
          associate: function (models) {
              // associations can be defined here
              Annotation.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: "userId"});
          },
      },
  });
  return Annotation;
};
```

**Corresponding migration file**

```
// migrations/20161121050521-create-annotation.js
const User = require("../models/user");
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Annotations', {
     id: {
       allowNull: false,
       autoIncrement: true,
       primaryKey: true,
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER
     },
     userId: {
       type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
       references: {model: User, key: 'id'},
       allowNull: false
     },
     ...
```

**Referenced Model**

```
// models/user.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        User.hasMany(models.Annotation, {foreignKey: "userId"});
      }
    }
  });
    return User;
};
```

I'm running the follow cli commands:
`"dropdb -U postgres annotate && curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'"`
`"createdb -U postgres annotate"`
`"node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate"`

When I migrate I get the following error:
`SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "User" does not exist`

From the documentation I was under the impression that `Annotation.belongsTo(models.User` would have been enough to establish the association, but when I did that my db tables didn't have any foreign key fields.

How can I establish tables with associations to one another?